# hibernate cascade to save parent and child

Tags: java, hibernate, cascade

i have 2 class. Parent and child. as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private List<Child> childs;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
    public List<Child> getChilds() {
        return childs;
    }
    @Id
    @Column(name="parent_name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }    

}
```

>

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name="parent_name")
    private Parent parent;

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

when i use session.save(parent) it saves parent and child in the database but the column of 
parent identifier in child table will remain null. so what is the problem?

Comment: how are u generating PK ID in Parent? I am not seeing it in code

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent") is saying hibernate to automatically create parent id in child

Answer (score 0):

try this on child Entity:

```
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Parent.class)

 @JoinColumn(name = "parent", nullable = false)
```

Comment: nothing changed. just an error about sql constraint violation :  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Column 'parent' cannot be null

Comment: I don't think hibernate will refresh the child when saving the parent. You could do it by yourself, like this:                                                           public void addChild(Child child) {
        this.childs.add(child); child.setParent(this);
    }

Comment: when i commit the transaction, hibernate will send query to fill columns such this(parent column in child table). so i think it is because i declared parent by myself in child and hibernate will no longer has the responsibility to fill it when commit. any way i will try fill it by my own if not any other opinion exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I declare OneToMany as Unidirectional, it works well.